# What does (n,) mean for a numpy array shape?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm starting out with Python and wondering why the size of an array is sometimes displayed as say (10,) instead of (10,1)? I'm also wondering if the difference affects any mathematical processing.

Comment: In what context? What kind of array are you talking about? Could you give vode examples?

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and guess that this is about numpy arrays.

Comment: @MegaIng: It's more a theoretical question. Any 1D numpy array, I mean.

Comment: If you are starting out with Python, you should wait a bit before diving into numpy

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The array could also have (1,10) shape, or even (1,10,1,1).  For some math that shape difference doesn't matter.  Shape details like this do make a difference when dealing with another array with a different shape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shape is a tuple, e.g. `(10, 1)`.

**Pop quiz:** How do we represent a one element tuple?

Does `(10)` work?

```
>>> type((10))
<class 'int'>
```

Nope. That's just a plain old `int`. Let's try `(10,)`:

```
>>> type((10,))
<class 'tuple'>
```

There we go! That produces a tuple, as desired. So we should write `(10,)`.

---

Try experimenting in your REPL.

```
>>> np.zeros((10,))
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])

>>> np.zeros((10,)).shape
(10,)


>>> np.zeros((10, 1))
array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]])

>>> np.zeros((10, 1)).shape
(10, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two is whether you have a 1D array `(10,)` or a 2D array where one dimension is of size 1 `(10,1)`.

Mathematical operations in numpy are quite robust. Although you might run into issues when broadcasting. For more details see: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html